# Short film series about a human crew with a doomsday weapon aimed at Earth

Tags: story-identification, tv

Looking this up for a friend:

> I watched this perhaps 15 years ago on TV. It was a series of short films like Twilight Zone.
>   One of the episodes was about a war between Earth (I think it was Earth) and an alien race. Aliens were never shown. There was a crew onboard an orbital station around Earth, and they had a doomsday weapon they should release on Earth in case aliens tried to invade it.
>   War was going bad and the crew lost radio communication with Earth. After some time a ship docks with them and they hear banging on the hatch, someone is trying to open it from the outside. They assume aliens won and drop the bomb. Then the hatch opens and its other people who tell them that Earth has won.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39278/movie-or-tv-film-full-story-happen-on-a-military-starship (which is later but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 17):

Sounds like [The Light Brigade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Light_Brigade_%28The_Outer_Limits%29) from the revamped Outer Limits series. This episode featured Robert Patrick and Wil Wheaton, two leading lights of geekdom.