# Movie or TV film - full story happen on a military starship,

Tags: story-identification, aliens

Almost 10 years ago I saw an English sci-fi film on a Hungarian TV channel.

The story was about a military mission started from Earth to an alien planet to destroy the whole race. The full story happened on the same starship (mainly the conversations and the mood of the film was interesting). The leaders of the mission has only one eye, because one of their eye was exchanged to a special monocular computer interface. This interface was used to unlock secret codes.

On the way to the alien planet some type of malfunction happened, and also some soldier died. Step by step, more army men died, and near to the end of film just a few people remained. They felt the mission is in danger and tried to save the situation. Finally only one young solder remained alive who launched the nuclear bomb carried by the starship to destroy the planet where the ship arrived. Unfortunately the ship arrived at Earth, because one alien lived with them on the ship and she reversed the ship at the middle of their travel.

This enemy alien looked like a normal man, because the aliens made surgical operations on one of their female specimens, and converted her to a human appearance.

Does anybody know the title of this film?

Comment: Was it maybe a TV episode? Sounds like an episode of Outer Limits that I remember. Did it have Wil Wheaton (AKA Wesley Crusher) in it?

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12885/90s-or-earlier-tv-episode-man-in-a-prison-cell-with-a-woman-being-changed-int (about the episode to which this is a sequel)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe this was an episode of The Outer Limits entitled [The Light Brigade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Light_Brigade_(The_Outer_Limits)).

Wil Wheaton did play the young cadet who (if I remember correctly) was only there because his father was a senior politician.

Comment: yes it is! :-) thanks.

Comment: Since this question has been repeatedly duped, I've taken the liberty of adding a vid for assisting future questioners.

Answer (score 12):

From your description, I believe this is an episode of The Outer Limits called [The Light Brigade (S2E18)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Light_Brigade_%28The_Outer_Limits%29).

The summary:

> Four soldiers, including repatriated prisoner of war Major John
>   Skokes, are the last survivors of a space battle. On board a crippled
>   cruiser, they are slowly dying of radiation poisoning, but they are
>   the only remaining chance to launch a strike against the alien enemy.

And:

> In the closing scene, at huge personal cost, the bomb is released over
>   what the crew believe to be the alien homeworld. It is in fact Earth,
>   and the mission is not only a failure, but the unleashing of the
>   doomsday weapon on an already crippled humanity.

I didn't personally remember the one-eyed crew member (I really only remember Wil Wheaton), but a quick Google search [found this](http://livedash.ark.com/transcript/the_outer_limits-%28the_light_brigade%29/204/KTVU/Monday_October_26_2009/101425/):

[image: One Eyed Crew]

Comment: yes! thank you .. this the movie i try to find :-)